# ¿Alguien puede ayudarme con este código de c++?

Tags: c++

Me da resultados erróneos en la multa.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a1, lm, fla, col, nc, il, ex, mul;
    int taj[a1][col];
    cout<<"La velocidad maxima es de 100 Km/h"<<endl;
    cout<<"Ingresar numero de infracciones obtenidas"<<endl;
    cin>>a1;
    lm=100;
    for (fla=0;fla<a1;fla++){
        for(col=0;col<3;col++){
            if (col==0){
                cout<<"Ingresar placa del vehiculo "<<fla+1<<endl;
                cin>>taj[fla][col]; 
            }
            if (col==1){
                do{ 
                cout<<"Ingresar cuadrante"<<endl;
                cin>>taj[fla][col]; 
                }while (taj[fla][col]>4||taj[fla][col]<1);  
                }
                if (col==2){

                    do {
                        cout<<"Ingresar velocidad del vehiculo "<<fla+1<<endl;
                    cin>>taj[fla][col];
                    }  while(taj[fla][col]<=100);
                }
            }   
        }
        fla=0;
        while (fla<a1){
                ex=taj[fla][2]-lm;
            mul=2000+(ex*125);
            cout<<"El vehiculo de placas: "<<taj[fla][0]<<", tiene una multa de: Q"<<mul<<endl;
            fla++;
        }
         return 0;
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el cuadro remarcado blanco, ese resultuado esta mal, ya que ingrese la misma velocidad en ambos vehículos, por lo que me tendría que dar la misma cantidad en la multa.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Por favor, revisa [tour] y [ask] para que te hagas una idea sobre cómo funciona este sitio. Estaría genial si indicases cual sería el resultado esperado y demás información que permita entender el problema...

Comment: En el programa se ingresa una cantidad  x de infracciones, y la velocidad que cada vehículo llevaba al momento de la infracción, esto: fla=0;
  while (fla<a1){
    ex=taj[fla][2]-lm;
   mul=2000+(ex*125);
   cout<<"El vehiculo de placas: "<<taj[fla][0]<<", tiene una multa de: Q"<<mul<<endl;
   fla++;
  }                                                                                                                   Tendría que darme cuanto se tiene que pagar de multa por vehículo, y da cantidades exageradas.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para añadir la información... los comentarios no deben usarse para eso sino para aclarar dudas

Comment: Lo siento. ¿Qué puede estar mal en el programa?

Comment: Sigues sin decir qué resultado esperas y cual obtienes... y sigues sin editar la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int taj[a1][col];
```

Presumiblemente esperabas que al declarar así el array, éste se adaptase perfectamente a las dimensiones introducidas por el usuario... pero:

1. El tamaño del array queda fijado en el momento de su declaración... y en ese momento las dimensiones **no** se han introducido (`a1` y `col`) tienen basura, luego el array tendrá un tamaño totalmente aleatorio (¿y si resulta que `a1` o `col` tiene un valor negativo? es aleatorio, así que es posible).
2. Un array basado en una dimensión variable se conoce como VLA (Variable Length Array) y no es una característica contemplada en el estándar de C++... algunos compiladores saben lidiar con ello pero yo no me arriesgaría a usarlo que lo mismo luego te falla en el examen o al presentar el ejercicio y la hemos liado.

Los sustitutos naturales son dos: Contenedores de la STL y memoria dinámica.

**contenedores**

El más común es `std::vector`, un contenedor que se adapta perfectamente al número de elementos que deba almacenar. Como necesitas dos dimensiones tendrás que concatenar dos vectores (cada uno te da una dimensión)

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> taj;
std::cin >> a1 >> col;

// opcion 1 -> le das las dimensiones a mano
taj.resize(a1);
for( int i=0; i<a1; i++ )
{
  taj[i].resize(col);
  for( int j=0; j<col; j++ )
    std::cin >> taj[i][j];

// opcion 2 -> vas añadiendo elementos sobre la marcha
taj[i].resize(col);
for( int i=0; i<a1; i++ )
{
  for( int j=0; j<col; j++ )
  {
    int valor;
    std::cin >> valor;
    taj[i].push_back(valor);
  }
}
```

**memoria dinamica**

Aqui toca mancharse las manos y usar `new` y `delete`:

```
int a1, col;
std::cin >> a1 >> col;
int**tam = new int*[a1];
for( int i=0; i<a1; i++ )
{
  tam[i] = new int[col];
  for( int j=0; j<col; j++ )
    std::cin >> tam[i][j];
}

// ...

// Liberar la memoria
for( int i=0; i<a1; i++ )
  delete[] tam[i];
delete[] tam;
```

Aunque claro, luego resulta que `col` es **siempre** igual a 3, luego es una variable que no tiene sentido:

```
struct datos
{
  int matricula;
  int cuadrante;
  int velocidad;
};

datos * taj = new datos[a1]; // yo cambiaria el nombre a a1 por numInfracciones o algo asi

for( int i=0; i<a1; i++ )
{
  std::cout << "Matricula: ";
  std::cin >> taj[i].matricula;

  std::cout << "Cuadrante: ";
  std::cin >> taj[i].cuadrante;

  do
  {
    std::cout << "Velocidad: ";
    std::cin >> taj[i].velocidad;
  } while( taj[i].velocidad <= 100 ); 
}

delete[] taj;
```

Ahora bien, dejarlo ya para nota implica quitar esa variable rara `lm` que pulula por ahí. En serio ¿Por qué esos nombres? Ten un poco más de cariño por el código.

Si la multa es a partir de 100, que es un valor fijo, entonces ese valor deberías almacenarlo en una constante:

```
int const VelocidadMaxima = 100;
```

Y usarlo en consecuencia:

```
}  while(taj[fla][col]<=VelocidadMaxima );

ex=taj[fla][2]-VelocidadMaxima;
```

Y, por favor, tabula correctamente el código.

Comment: Gracias por las correcciones, tendré en cuenta todo.